# Properties of the fundamental group scheme of a compact Riemann surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be a smooth, complex Riemann surface of genus $g \ge 2$. Fix a point $x \in X$ and denote by $\pi$ the fundamental group scheme of $X$ with base point $x$. I have the following questions:

Is $\pi$ a Lie group? What is the maximal torus of $\pi$?

Comment: I assume you meant compact. In any case $\pi$ is not a Lie group.

Comment: It is a Lie group (when equipped with discrete topology). What is your definition of a maximal torus in a discrete group? (The standard ones work for connected Lie groups or algebraic groups.)